# Hosting docker container to a local network

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Is there a way to host a container to be accessible only from local network? I'm using Ubuntu and I found the option to run docker with -p command but I'm not sure if the container will be accessible only from a local network.

Comment: The container will be accessible to anyone that can reach that port on your host. If you are behind a firewall, then it's only accessible to connections permitted by that firewall.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your docker container on your local machine it is available only from your local environment

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.